# Let the highest element control the flex wrapper height

Tags: javascript, css, layout, flexbox

I'm designing a footer mega menu containing a number of submenus. The content is dynamic. I want to make the largest submenu span a whole column of the wrapper, and therefore also set the height of it.

I've come up with a solution where I'm measuring the height of the blocks and sets the wrapper height to the height of the highest block.

**While this works OK - The solution feels a bit naive and something tells me there are more elegant solutions to it. Preferably without javascript. What do you think?**  I tried with CSS grid but could not get the result I wished for.

```
nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

The height of the wrapper element is set with Javascript

```
/*
  Set the height of the wrapper to the highest blocks height
*/
function rearrangeBlocks() {
  // Grab the whole menu
  const section = document.querySelector('nav');
  // Grab all the blocks
  const allBlocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block');
  // Grab the highest block
  const longestBlock = Array.from(allBlocks).reduce((longest, current) => {
    if (current.getBoundingClientRect().height > longest.getBoundingClientRect().height) {
     return current; 
    } else {
      return longest;
    }
  });

  // Set the height of the menu to the same height of the highest menu item
  section.style.height = `${longestBlock.offsetHeight}px`;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/hanserikb/pen/xyeYqv)

Comment: Both Flexbox and CSS-Grid would require you to use **rows** which can then be equalised in height to the tallest. In fact JS might be the simplest option here.

Answer (score 0):

Change some CSS

```
nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: red;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RemZmb